# Is there a way to calculate property value by means of Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a `dataSource` bean. I need to extract a boolean value from it:

```
dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().supportsStoredProcedures()
```

and then use it inside my DAO to define behavior.

The obvious way to get this value is to inject `dataSource` directly to my DAO class (currently it uses only EntityManager). 
But I'm curious is there a way to get only boolean flag value?

Can we use spring expression language inside `@Value` annotation to calculate the flag?
Or is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Something like This?

[Spring XML]

```
    <util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:com/acme/app/myprops.properties"/>
```

[Java]

```
    @Value("#{myProps.hostname}")
    public void setHostName(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }
```

Source: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69602-Value-and-PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: Specifically... @Value("#{datasource.connection.metaData.supportsStoredProcedures()}")